# Matching a user to a message using Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm currently writing a social networking app for iOS using Swift and the Parse SDK. My app is basically a `UITableView` that displays a timeline of messages from users that sign up for my app. But there is one part that I'm struggling with that I hope the community will be able to help me solve.

My problem is that I want a user to able to tap on a message in my tableview and display the contents of the message and the user that sent it in a `UILabel`. I pretty much have tried everything I could think of to create this logic but I seem to make things worse. I'm pretty sure a `PFquery` needs to be used somewhere in this logic. I will attach my source code for my `TimelineTableViewController` and my custom tableview cell. Full code examples on how to achieve this logic in Swift will be very helpful since I'm already behind.

Thanks in advance

Derek Cacciotti

Twitter: @derekcacciotti

[TimelineTableViewController](https://groups.google.com/group/parse-developers/attach/ac36e9c13a17c4d8/TimelineTableViewController.swift?part=0.1&authuser=0)

[TableViewCell](https://groups.google.com/group/parse-developers/attach/ac36e9c13a17c4d8/MessageTableViewCell.swift?part=0.2&authuser=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, use the `indexPath` to help you figure out which message was tapped like so:

```
let message: PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
```

From there, get the values of your message by key (or create a `Message` class that is a proper [PFObject subclass](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-defining/iOS)), then use those values to construct a string for your label.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful but, When i set my messageLabel using  self.messageLabel.text = message["message"] I get a error that says: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  Any Idea to fix this? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to understand how optionals work in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: @huhitschirs Thanks, I figured it out, I appreciate your help :)